# conflict exist with definition "id' and "r" in namespace internal

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

I have this code in the beginning of my SWF witch is a banner ad.

```
var id:String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.id;
var r:URLRequest = new URLRequest("javascript:expandEaFloating(" + id + ")");
navigateToURL(r,'_self');
```

So this code is calling a java script function witch is opening the floating banner so it can be visible.

Then when the animation is over it has to be closed with this code :

```
var id:String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.id;
var r:URLRequest = new URLRequest("javascript:collapseEaFloating(" + id + ")");
navigateToURL(r,'_self');
```

I've put this code in frame 500 where my animation stops, and shows me :  "there is an conflict exist with definition "id' and "r" in namespace internal.

Comment: don't you missing extra single quotes around the id? in (' " + id + " ') ?

Comment: ExternalInterface is more suitable for calling JS from AS3, try to replace navigateToURL to ExtarnalInterfece.call("collapseEaFloating", id) first, and I agree with @salexch about missing qoutes in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Give `id` and `r` different names.

```
var targetID:String = root.loaderInfo.parameters.id;
var jsRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest("javascript:expandEaFloating(" + targetID + ")");
navigateToURL(jsRequest,'_self');
```